# AngularJS, how to use min="" on select > options to validate form?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Say for example that I have this code:

```
<form name="myForm">
<select id="mySelect" required min="1" ng-model="foo">
  <option value="0">Zero</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<button>My Button would go here</button>
</form>
```

As you can probably tell, my goal is to make sure that the form is invalid if the option Zero is selected (because the minimum number is 1). However, for one reason or another, this does not work. How would one go about seeing that the min="" applies to the values?

And, no, in my case I cannot take out the option of zero, I would need to validate it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Could you leave the option "Zero" but no value, which the "required" attribute would catch?

```
<form name="myForm">
<select id="mySelect" required ng-model="foo">
  <option value="">Zero</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<button>My Button would go here</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot use value="" and required like in the answer from Nicholas Smith then you can also use

```
 ng-required="foo > 0"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach here would be to add a custom validation directive to extend the reach of `ngMin` with `<select>` elements:

```
yourModule.directive('selectMin', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
      ngMin: '='
    },
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModelController) {
      ngModelController.$validators.min = function (value) {
        if (value) {
          return value >= $scope.ngMin;
        }

        return true;
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Usage:

```
<select id="mySelect" required select-min ng-min="1" ng-model="foo">
  <option value="0">Zero</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```